# Duda orden ascendente / descendente

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario con el que recojo los datos en un array.

```
$dato1 = $_REQUEST['nombre'];
$dato2 = $_REQUEST['director'];
$dato3 = $_REQUEST['año'];
$dato4 = $_REQUEST['genero'];
$dato5 = $_REQUEST['duracion'];

$alumno = array("nombre" => "$dato1","director" => "$dato2","año" => "$dato3","genero" => "$dato4","duracion" => "$dato5");
$_SESSION['lista'][] = $alumno;
```

Y luego tengo otro formulario para que indique como quiero ordenar, y una función para cada campo.

La función que me ordena alfabéticamente, pero quiero añadirle orden ascendente o descendente.

```
function comparatitulo ($x, $y) {
    if ($x['nombre'] == $y['nombre']){
        return 0;
    }elseif ($x['nombre'] < $y['nombre']){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}
uasort ($_SESSION['lista'], 'comparatitulo');
break;
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. ¿Qué es lo que quieres ordenar? Da un ejemplo. Creo que se puede hacer mucho más simple con funciones de array.

Comment: Tengo un formulario con el que recojo los datos en un array         
,$dato1 = $_REQUEST['nombre'];
$dato2 = $_REQUEST['director'];
$dato3 = $_REQUEST['año'];
$dato4 = $_REQUEST['genero'];
$dato5 = $_REQUEST['duracion'];
    
                    $alumno = array("nombre" => "$dato1","director" => "$dato2","año" => "$dato3","genero" => "$dato4","duracion" => "$dato5");
                    $_SESSION['lista'][] = $alumno;                                                                      y luego lo ordeno con la función correspondiente.

Comment: Todavía no entiendo. Por ejemplo, `$_REQUEST` es ya un array, ¿para qué creas otro array? Y tampoco entiendo todavía qué es lo que quieres ordenar, si son varios datos (filas), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando comparas los valores en tu función para ordernar en ascendente usas < y en desc >, así que un modo muy sencillo con tu código es crear una función para oredenar en ascendente y otra en descendente y usar la que necesites en cada momento.

```
$a_tittles[0]['nombre'] = "aaa";
$a_tittles[1]['nombre'] = "bbb";
$a_tittles[2]['nombre'] = "ccc";

function comparatituloasc ($x, $y) {
   if ($x['nombre'] == $y['nombre']) { return 0;
   } else if ($x['nombre'] < $y['nombre']) { return -1;
   } else { return 1; }      
}

function comparatitulodesc ($x, $y) {
   if ($x['nombre'] == $y['nombre']) { return 0;
   } else if ($x['nombre'] > $y['nombre']){ return -1;
   } else { return 1; }      
}    

uasort ($a_tittles, 'comparatituloasc');    //Orden asc
foreach ($a_tittles as $title) { echo $title['nombre']."-"; }
//aaa-bbb-ccc-
uasort ($a_tittles, 'comparatitulodesc');    //Orden desc    
foreach ($a_tittles as $title) { echo $title['nombre']."-"; }
//ccc-bbb-aaa-
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba